Debugging Web Client Code in Visual Studio Code With Chrome Launched by Visual Studio Debugger
Background:
I use both visual studio and visual studio code to manage my project, I use visual studio to edit code for my backend and to run the debugger to debug my backend. I use visual studio code to edit frontend code and to debug that code. I do this because I find that Visual Studio in my case doesn't play well with Typescript and React.
It seems to be difficult to get your visual studio code debugger to connect to a chrome instance which was started by a Web Project in Visual studio. The biggest issue is getting Visual Studio Code to Connect to the Chrome instance that Visual Studio launches. Visual Studio doesn't seem to allow you to add additional browsers via the "Browse With..." command. This seems to be an issue with newer versions of Visual Studio specifically, 2017 and newer.
For the sake of any others attempting to do what I did, I have documented my approach in the answer to hopefully save others days of research and trial and error.

To get this working, I had to do some weird customization:
First in Visual Studio Code, I created a launch.json script for attaching to Chrome (launch.json lives in the .vscode folder in the project directory).
That file looks like this:
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach VS Chrome",
      "address": "localhost",
      "port": 9229,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/../wwwroot/**/*.js",
      ],

    }
  ]
}

keep note of the "port" value, this will need to be remembered for the Visual Studio setup.
In order to connect to the chrome instance it needs to be ran with following argument --remote-debugging-port=<port> where  is the same as in the launch.json file.
This is tricky to set up in Visual Studio if you aren't using the IIS Express Profile. Mine uses my Web Project's own Profile Configuration.
In order to get Chrome to launch with this argument whenever we run the VS debugger, we have to add a new browser configuration. For whatever reason, you can't do this while targeting your Web Project's Debug Profile.
In order to setup a new Browser Configuration, we have to swap to the IIS Express Profile:

Then we can Click "Browse With...", If we try this while our Web Project's Debug Profile is selected, it silently fails and never opens the modal we need.
(NOTE: project will need to be able to build at this point to change this)
A modal should appear for you to select a browser to use, from here we can add a new Browser by clicking the "Add..." button.
Use the Chrome Executable path in "Program" field (can get this by copying the existing Chrome Browser Configuration's Program path).
Set Arguments to the command above: --remote-debugging-port=<port> (where  is the same value from your launch.json)
Set the name to something meaningful like "Google Chrome (VSCode Debugging)" to identify later.
Optional: Set as default right on this modal
After that has been added, close the modal or hit cancel, then you can switch back to your Project's Debug Profile and select the new Browser as the default to launch with.
After it launches you should be able to set break points in Visual Studio Code and run that debugger as well.
